# finding user group name while logging with glassfish jdbcRealm

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish-3

I know that while user logs in we can find the user name by

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
       HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
request.login(username, password);
Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
principal.getName();
```

but how do i get the user Group (without doing any db query).

I tried the below but it doesn't work, it always returns false for all group.

```
context.getExternalContext().isUserInRole("USER")
request.isUserInRole("USER")
```

Comment: have you mapped groups to roles in glassfish-web.xml on in domain.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that groups and roles are different concepts.

Suppose you have a web app where someone can write articles, someone can only comment and others can only read. So you have three roles: WRITER, COMMENTER and READER.

Now this web app is used internally to your organization. The organigram provides these groups: PROJECTMANAGER, ARCHITECT, SYSADMIN and DEVELOPER.

In few words roles are related to webapp, groups are related to your organigram.

In glassfish-web.xml you can bind groups and/or users to roles. For example PROJECTMANAGERs and ARCHITECTs are WRITERs, SYSADMINs are COMMENTERs and DEVELOPERs are READERs.

Thus in general there is no way to retrieve users's groups without a db query. Anyway a ploy is to create roles with the same name as groups (in glassfish-web.xml). Besides in the admin console there is a flag to automatically maps roles to groups.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts to augment Alf's informative response:

1. A user may belong to multiple groups.
2. Each group may be have associated with it multiple roles.  For GlassFish 3.1.2 the mapping between roles and groups is made in `glassfish-web.xml`, i.e:

   ```
   <security-role-mapping>
     <role-name>USER</role-name>
     <group-name>USER</group-name>
   </security-role-mapping>
   ```
3. Roles must be defined to your web-app, in `web.xml`:

   ```
   <security-role>
     <role-name>USER</role-name>
   </security-role>
   ```

The above maps a group `USER` into a role `USER` in the web-app.  Certainly you can choose names that differ - just keep the same value in the `role-name` elements for both.